# pig unable to load data from blob storage

Tags: hadoop, azure-blob-storage, apache-pig

I have a problem in loading data into my pig, Actually I created a container in my storage and upload some text files, but When I wanted to load my data into pig(grunt) it said that can't read data from input. I used `asv://container@account.blob.core.windows.net/name.txt` but unfortunately it couldn't read from input and give some errors.

1. Just created a cluster on Azure
2. Loaded some data into ASV
3. Want to load that into Pig and then dump.
4. I can `cat` the file I can do everything else with the file but Pig does not like.

and there are some of errors:

Input(s):

> Failed to read data from "asv://123@faraz.blob.core.windows.net/name.txt "

Output(s):

> Failed to produce result in "asv://test@faraz.blob.core.windows.net/tmp/temp-107
>   5234199/tmp-1250521031"
>   Could anyone tell me what should I do?
>   thanks